# How to create a bootable usb stick for ubuntu on RHEL 6

Tags: ubuntu, usb, installation, redhat-enterprise-linux

**NOTE**: this question was asked in [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/550094/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-stick-for-ubuntu-on-rhel-6), and I was suggested to ask here.

I want to create a bootable usb stick for installing ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. Currently I have access to an RHEL 6 machine.

Ubuntu has [guides for installing from usb stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick), and two methods mentioned are: 1. Unetbootin and 2. mksub. I tried to install unetbootin on RHEL 6, which failed with the error `Error: Package: unetbootin-0-15.585bzr.el6.x86_64 (epel) Requires: syslinux-extlinux`. Also, `yum search mksub` returned nothing (as well as my Google search didn't return anything useful).

I was wondering if anyone has experience in creating Ubuntu installer stick from RHEL 6. Thanks.

Comment: Can you install or do you have installed `grub-pc-bin` or `isolinux` packages?

Answer (score 5):

Just use DD, it's a command line program included on most Linux distros. This method works for many distros, not just Ubuntu.

> dd if=/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdb

replace `sdb` with usb drive letter (eg: sdb, sdc, sdd, sde, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your RHEL distro is missing syslinux package.
You can install it as RPM:

```
rmp -ihv ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/x86_64/testing/RPMS/syslinux-4.04-0.pre14.el6.rft.x86_64.rpm
```

Another option,try http://iso2usb.sourceforge.net/

It should work on RHEL/CentOS